# Change posion:fixed of form to postion:static on the bootom of website after change browser size to 425px width of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which has fixed position. But when I have mobile width for ex.425 px of browser I'd like the form to put into new div with static position.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an example of what you hope to achieve. Its not easy to guess what you want.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please kindly read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , When you asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a webiste with the form which has postion fixed. When the page is scrolled down the form stay in one place as it should be. In higher width on laptop or compter it is very good but when I open the site on mobile the form cover the contet, so I'd like to put this form to the bottom of the page into the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the form where you would like it mobile first and then change the css

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <form >
      //your form
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
form {
    position: relative;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px) {
   form {
       position: fixed;
   }
}
```

Comment: No problem, just make sure in future to ask your question in a similar way to how I've answered your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  div {
    position: static
  }
}
```